# Formatting inside a form field on a locked word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to be able to write material with formatting like colors, font and text size in a form field on a locked word document.

I also need to be able to cut and paste pre-formatted material into these form field on a locked word document.

It's for an assessment book where students enter or cut and paste formatted lists like evacuation procedures or information sheets.

I need to keep the document locked but allow students to enter this formatted text in to the form fields.